# Why does GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl return no rights in this case?

Tags: c++, winapi

I think `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl` should return that I have at least a couple of rights in this situation, but it gives me 0.

I use SDDL to create an ACL with two entries, one granting generic all rights (`GA`) to a named SID and another granting generic read rights (`GR`) to the world sid. Then I create a second instance of that SID, wrap it in a trustee, and pass it into `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl`. I expect that it will give me generic all rights, potentially with some other inherited rights. However, the code below prints 0 (Visual Studio Community 15.9.7).

```cpp
int main() {
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;
    PSID sid;
    TRUSTEE_A trustee;
    PACL dacl;

    if (!ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptorA(
        "D:(A;;GA;;;S-1-5-1-2-3)(A;;GR;;;WD)",
        SDDL_REVISION_1,
        &sd,
        nullptr
    )){
        // Error handling omitted
    }

    if (!ConvertStringSidToSidA("S-1-5-1-2-3", &sid)) {
        // Error handling omitted
    }

    BuildTrusteeWithSidA(&trustee, sid);

    BOOL present;
    BOOL defaulted;
    if (!GetSecurityDescriptorDacl(sd, &present, &dacl, &defaulted)) {
        // Error handling omitted
    }

    ACCESS_MASK access;
    if (GetEffectiveRightsFromAclA(dacl, &trustee, &access) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        // Error handling omitted
    }

    std::cout << access << std::endl;

    LocalFree(sid);
    LocalFree(sd);
}
```

Is there something wrong with the ACL format? Are generic rights not usable in this situation?

Comment: generic rights not usable in this situation. `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl` not good design api.

Answer (score 0):

The `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl` function is intended to search an `ACL` and return an access mask that indicates access allowed to a trustee by a `DACL`. Sounds very convenient! Such a function could potentially remove our need to search a `DACL` for `ACEs` before adding our own `ACEs`. `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl`, however, attempts to do too much, and thus ends up doing almost nothing of use.

`GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl` figures out the access allowed based on a composite of the matching access-allowed `ACEs`, and then subtracts a composite of the matching access-denied `ACEs`. What this means is that `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl` can return a set of access rights indicating that the `ACL` does not award the access I want for my trustee.

The more useful functions `SetEntriesInAcl` and `GetExplicitEntriesFromAcl`are intended to relieve you of the responsibility of allocating memory for `ACEs` and `ACLs` while still allowing you to deal with the `ACL` directly. The goal of these functions is great, but the functions have a sordid history of bugs and performance issues. Some of these problems have been cleared up, but if you choose to use these functions in your projects, it is important that you thoroughly test the code that uses them.

You can also refer to the following information：
https://flylib.com/books/en/4.420.1.83/1/

Comment: Hey Strive, it seems like the way you wrote it, all these functions you named are things to be avoided... is there any good way to go about this, like the Authz way?